# Divs side by side and centered

Tags: html, center, css

I have a block of *divs* and I need to align them centered.

I have sucessfully put them side by side, but it´s dinamic and the last one needs to be centered.

Here is my *CSS*:

```
.mosaicoBox {
width:170px;
height:165px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
text-align:center;
float:left;
padding:0 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
display:inline;
margin-right:8px;
}
```

Here is my *HTML*:

```
<center><br /><h3>Sistema TMJ</h3><br />
<div class="mosaicoBox mosaicoBoxOff " align="center">
<img src="../res/mosaico/111/th120x120_111.jpg" class="blank">
<div class="textMosaico">
<span class="orange">Apresentação do Sistema TMJ</span><br />
<span style="font-size:10px;">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nwpPDX4RVSk?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;autoplay=1" 
onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, {objectType: 'iframe', width: 480, height: 385, 
allowSizeReduction: false, wrapperClassName: 'draggable-header no-footer', 
preserveContent: false, objectLoadTime: 'after'})"
class="highslide">assistir</a>
| <a target="_blank" href="../res/mosaico/111/mosaico111.wmv" title="Formato WMV ()">download</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mosaicoBox mosaicoBoxOff " align="center">
<img src="../res/mosaico/112/th120x120_112.jpg" class="blank">
<div class="textMosaico">
<span class="orange">Moldagem do aparelho TMD</span><br />
<span style="font-size:10px;">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/J6corp_ZNoE?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;autoplay=1" 
onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, {objectType: 'iframe', width: 480, height: 385, 
allowSizeReduction: false, wrapperClassName: 'draggable-header no-footer', 
preserveContent: false, objectLoadTime: 'after'})"
class="highslide">assistir</a>
| <a target="_blank" href="../res/mosaico/112/mosaico112.wmv" title="Formato WMV ()">download</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mosaicoBox mosaicoBoxOff " align="center">
<img src="../res/mosaico/113/th120x120_113.jpg" class="blank">
<div class="textMosaico">
<span class="orange">Opinião do Dentista</span><br />
<span style="font-size:10px;">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bBBbCAjR7iY?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;autoplay=1" 
onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, {objectType: 'iframe', width: 480, height: 385, 
allowSizeReduction: false, wrapperClassName: 'draggable-header no-footer', 
preserveContent: false, objectLoadTime: 'after'})"
class="highslide">assistir</a>
| <a target="_blank" href="../res/mosaico/113/mosaico113.wmv" title="Formato WMV ()">download</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</center>
<div class="separador">
</div>
```

So the last row is always on the left because of **float:left** in the *css*. I have tried to pu all this in another *div* with **text-align:center** and the inside *divs* with **display:inline** intead of **float:left**, but it scrambled it. What´s the solution for that? T

hanks for help.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `inilne-block` for this &n `text-align:center` to it's `parent` like this:

```
.parent{text-align:center}

.child{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display:inline-block
}
```

check this  http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/jXXJQ/2/

Comment: Got it!!! But **inline-table** was better because **inline-block** was aligning divs down and I needed this to be aligned up.

Comment: but inline-block is better because it's work in IE with css hack & for previous example there is an problem with markup not with css check this http://jsfiddle.net/MKpxy/

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper for these three boxes, div which will hold them together.

```
body {margin:0; padding:0}
.mosaicoWrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
}
```

and in html your code:

```
<div class="mosaicoWrapper">
<!-- Your code -->
<div class="separador"></div>
```

That should do the trick :-)

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/jXXJQ/1/

Comment: Can't fix by 600px because it´s dinamic: it's 4 cols by now, but it can be only one, two or three divs. And with the **float:left* the DIVs will never align to center...

Comment: Not perfect but might be helpful:
`.mosaicoWrapper {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    left:25%;
    width:auto;
}`