# Align two HTML elements in the center and display side-by-side in markdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, markdown

I am using github flavored markdown to format my github profile and I wanted to show an image alongside the profile views.

This is what I achieved so far:

[image]

With this markdown code:

```
<details>
    <summary>Hello, friend</summary>
    <p>
      <img src="https://github.com/AleixMT/AleixMT/assets/23342150/a802e799-cfcf-4add-ae22-0aa96bbecb6c" alt="lol-haha" style="height:3.8cm;">
      <img src="https://komarev.com/ghpvc/?username=aleixmt&label=Profile%20views&color=0e75b6&style=flat" alt="aleixmt" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;"> 
    </p>
</details>
```

This code also adds a dropdown menu to see the images, I actually do not need that.

What I want is the profile view counter to be in the middle of the height of the image, still on its right side, so it is positioned with more height.

I should see it like this:

[image]

Can someone please help me? I am completely new with HTML and markdown and I did not know that aligning two elements was going to be so difficult. Bless front-end programmers.

Also note that the two elements must be displayed in the center of the page.

Do not use CSS to format the elements, add the styles in line since in markdown there is no support for explicit CSS. Also please test your solution since I have been using other solutions but they do not work with github flavored markdown:

- [CSS - center two images in css side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819417/css-center-two-images-in-css-side-by-side)
- [Markdown and image alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255170/markdown-and-image-alignment)
- [Divs side by side and centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915791/divs-side-by-side-and-centered)
- [is there a way to align two HTML elements side by side without CSS? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554639/is-there-a-way-to-align-two-html-elements-side-by-side-without-css-how) (my code is similar to this)
- [vertical middle aligned image and text side-by-side in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101813/vertical-middle-aligned-image-and-text-side-by-side-in-css) (this looks good but does not work..)

Thank you very much.

EDIT: I finally was able to use a table with inline CSS styles as asked for solving my question.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/AleixMT) to see the final result.

Comment: The GitHub README.md doesn't allow for much layout. It's very limited in what it will allow, so you'd best read up on what it can do. (There are plenty of tutorials online.) But Markdown is not a layout tool. It's really for making up text. Maybe look at GitHub profiles you like and look at how they've done what they do. But I haven't seen any with anything more than very basic, linear layout (that is, one thing above another).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers are provided for this question that solve my problem. Luckily, [I have found a solution in here](http://jiewang.name/posts/2020/03/images/). I think I have used the table layout. My solution code using only inline CSS styles is:

```
<!-- Eliot Alderson + profile visits counter -->
<div id="image-table" align="center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:10px">
                <img src="https://github.com/AleixMT/AleixMT/assets/23342150/a802e799-cfcf-4add-ae22-0aa96bbecb6c"/>
            </td>
            <td style="padding:10px">
                <img src="https://komarev.com/ghpvc/?username=aleixmt&label=Profile%20views&color=0e75b6&style=flat"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

I hope this helps someone. I will mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can put both components into a table:

```css
td {
vertical-align:center
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://github.com/AleixMT/AleixMT/assets/23342150/a802e799-cfcf-4add-ae22-0aa96bbecb6c" alt="lol-haha" style="height:3.8cm;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://komarev.com/ghpvc/?username=aleixmt&label=Profile%20views&color=0e75b6&style=flat" alt="aleixmt" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Edit 1: I previously used a table but that's not recommended according to [@Sdili_81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431505/align-two-html-elements-in-the-center-and-display-side-by-side-in-markdown/76431607?noredirect=1#comment134771913_76431607)

Edit 2: Reverted back to the original answer as this solution did not work in this particular use case.

Comment: Don't use table for layout in the 2023 please

Comment: Why not? What do you suggest instead?

Comment: Because tables are for tabled data and not for layout. There are more moderns way like flexbox or grid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you put the CSS in line? As far as I know there is no way to explicitly declare css in a markdown format

Comment: you can insert it into the <td> field just write <td style="vertical-align: center;">

Comment: @Sfili_81 I changed the answer according to your suggestion

Comment: It would be fine using more "modern" methods, but I am not here to get a fancy solution, I am here to get a solution, and this solution with the grids does not work. Can you restore your answer with a table? I would like to try it as well.

Comment: Just reverted it back, please accept my answer to show the question is solved - Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bro-code{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<p class="bro-code">
      <img src="https://github.com/AleixMT/AleixMT/assets/23342150/a802e799-cfcf-4add-ae22-0aa96bbecb6c" alt="lol-haha" style="height:3.8cm;">
      <img src="https://komarev.com/ghpvc/?username=aleixmt&label=Profile%20views&color=0e75b6&style=flat" alt="aleixmt" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;"> 
    </p>
```

Comment: Not working, it stays the same as my proposed solution. This is the code that I have written without CSS:

<p display:flex; align-items:center;>
      <img src="https://github.com/AleixMT/AleixMT/assets/23342150/a802e799-cfcf-4add-ae22-0aa96bbecb6c" alt="lol-haha" style="height:3.8cm;">
      <img src="https://komarev.com/ghpvc/?username=aleixmt&label=Profile%20views&color=0e75b6&style=flat" alt="aleixmt" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;"> 
    </p>